# Compare columns A,B & C and return values of col D when matching

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I asked this question the other day ["Use GAS to search col A and return values of col B when matching"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57228679/use-gas-to-search-col-a-and-return-values-of-col-b-when-matching/57229553#57229553) and received an answer which works perfectly!

But now I'm trying to modify the code to compare all of the previously selected column values and return the next value (B-E).  So after projectTasksAdj!B5 is selected, the values from projectTasks!A5:B5 will be used to populate the data validation of projectTasksAdj!C5 and so on until projectTasksAdj!E5.

I only asked for the last process `A & B & C & D` though because I figured I could just trim it down myself as needed.

[Here's a link to my sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-FdpxsNcrqXXWroYzeAQZz5TuyEX6xKnTif0rrrJl60/edit#gid=1277145684&range=A3)

Here is my current script

```js
function projectTasksAdjDV(e) {
  var ptaSh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('projectTasksAdj');  
  var ptSh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('projectTasks');
  var foundValues = [];  
  var foundValues2 = [];  
  var foundValues3 = [];  
  var activeCell = ptaSh.getActiveCell();    
  const valueToFind = activeCell.getValue();

  if(activeCell.getColumn()==1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
    var data=ptSh.getRange(3,1,ptaSh.getLastRow(),2).getValues(); // changed ptaSht

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
        foundValues.push(data[i][1]);
      }
    }

    var colBValidationRange = foundValues;
    var colBValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colBValidationRange).build();
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colBValidationRule);

  }

  //  Populate column C, D & E data validations

  Logger.log("getColumn = " + activeCell.getColumn());
  Logger.log("getRow = " + activeCell.getRow());

  if(activeCell.getColumn() > 1 && activeCell.getColumn()<4 && activeCell.getRow()>1){
    Logger.log("Row > 1 && Column < 4");

    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
    activeCell.offset(0, 2).clearDataValidations();
    activeCell.offset(0, 3).clearDataValidations();

    var ptadata=ptaSh.getRange(3,1,ptaSh.getLastRow(),5).getValues();
    var ptdata=ptSh.getRange(3,4,ptSh.getLastRow(),5).getValues();

    for(var i=0;i<ptadata.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==ptadata[i][0]) {
        foundValues.push(ptdata[i][0]);
      }
      Logger.log("foundValues = " + foundValues);

      if(valueToFind==ptadata[i][1]) {
        foundValues2.push(ptdata[i][0]);
      }
      Logger.log("foundValues2 = " + foundValues2);

      if(valueToFind==ptadata[i][2]) {
        foundValues3.push(ptdata[i][0]);
      }
      Logger.log("foundValues3 = " + foundValues3);

    }
    var colCValidationRange = foundValues;
    var colCValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colCValidationRange).build();
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colCValidationRule);
    var colDValidationRange = foundValues2;
    var colDValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colDValidationRange).build();
    activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(colDValidationRule);
    var colEValidationRange = foundValues3;
    var colEValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colEValidationRange).build();
    activeCell.offset(0, 3).setDataValidation(colEValidationRule);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wound up with.  It could probably be made more streamline or efficient, but it seems to be working so far.  Thank you @MiMi (and Cooper...) for all of your help!  You taught me several things.  Thank you!

I start by filtering all possibilities that match column A, then B,C,D and finally E is an exact match.  But the following column's data validation is "re-populated" with each selection.

Please feel free to critique what I've done as I'm still learning and very likely have some redundancy going on.

```js
function projectTasksAdjDV(e) {  
  var activess = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('projectTasksAdj');  
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('projectTasks');

  var colAValues = [];  
  var foundBValues = [];  
  var foundCValues = [];  
  var foundDValues = [];  
  var foundEValues = [];  
  var activeCell = activess.getActiveCell();  
  var data = datass.getRange(3,1,datass.getLastRow(),7).getValues();
  const valueToFind = activeCell.getValue();
  const colAVal = data;
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(colAVal==data[i][1]) {
        colAValues.push(data[i][0]);
      }
    }

  //  Couldn't seem to get indexOf to work properly
  //  so this is my "workaround".

  var colIndex = activess.getActiveCell().getColumn();

  //  Populate column B data validations
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 2){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
    activeCell.offset(0, 2).clearDataValidations();
    activeCell.offset(0, 3).clearDataValidations();
    activeCell.offset(0, 4).clearDataValidations();
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
        foundBValues.push(data[i][1]);
      }
    }
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {      
      if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
        foundCValues.push(data[i][2]);
      }
    }
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
        foundDValues.push(data[i][3]);
      }
    }
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
        foundEValues.push(data[i][6]);
      }
    }
    if(colIndex != 0){      
      var colBValidationRange = foundBValues;
      var colBValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colBValidationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colBValidationRule);
      var colCValidationRange = foundCValues;
      var colCValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colCValidationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(colCValidationRule);
      var colDValidationRange = foundDValues;
      var colDValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colDValidationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 3).setDataValidation(colDValidationRule);
      var colEValidationRange = foundEValues;
      var colEValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colEValidationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 4).setDataValidation(colEValidationRule);
    }      
  }

  //  Populate column C data validations
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 2 && activeCell.getRow() > 2){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
    activeCell.offset(0, 2).clearDataValidations();
    activeCell.offset(0, 3).clearDataValidations();
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {      
      if(valueToFind==data[i][1]) {
        foundCValues.push(data[i][2]);
      }
    }
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==data[i][1]) {
        foundDValues.push(data[i][3]);
      }
    }
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==data[i][1]) {
        foundEValues.push(data[i][6]);
      }
    }
    if(colIndex != 0){      
      var colCValidationRange = foundCValues;
      var colCValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colCValidationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colCValidationRule);
      var colDValidationRange = foundDValues;
      var colDValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colDValidationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(colDValidationRule);
      var colEValidationRange = foundEValues;
      var colEValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colEValidationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 3).setDataValidation(colEValidationRule);
    }      
  }

  //  Populate column D data validations
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 3 && activeCell.getRow() > 2){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
    activeCell.offset(0, 2).clearDataValidations();
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==data[i][2]) {
        foundDValues.push(data[i][3]);
      }
    }
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==data[i][2]) {
        foundEValues.push(data[i][6]);
      }
    }
    if(colIndex != 0){            
      var colDValidationRange = foundDValues;
      var colDValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colDValidationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colDValidationRule);
      var colEValidationRange = foundEValues;
      var colEValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colEValidationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(colEValidationRule);
    }      
  }

  //  Populate column E data validations
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 4 && activeCell.getRow() > 2){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==data[i][3] && data[0][0]==data[i][0]) {
        foundEValues.push(data[i][6]);
      }
    }
    if(colIndex != 0){      
      var colEValidationRange = foundEValues;
      var colEValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colEValidationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colEValidationRule);
    }      
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that those 4 loops could be written like this:`for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
  if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
    foundBValues.push(data[i][1]);
  }
  if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
    foundCValues.push(data[i][2]);
  }
  if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
    foundDValues.push(data[i][3]);
  }
  if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
    foundEValues.push(data[i][6]);
  }
  if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
    foundEValues.push(data[i][6]);
  }
}
`Same for atleast two other loops

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this in your code `if(activeCell.getColumn() != 0){` and it is always true for any active cell.

```
function projectTasksAdjDV(e) {
  var ptaSh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('projectTasksAdj');  
  var ptSh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('projectTasks');
  var foundValues = [];  
  var foundValues2 = [];  
  var foundValues3 = [];  
  var activeCell = ptaSh.getActiveCell();    
  const valueToFind = activeCell.getValue();

  if(activeCell.getColumn()==1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
    var data=ptaSh.getRange(3,1,ptaSht.getLastRow(),2).getValues();

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==data[i][0]) {
        foundValues.push(data[i][1]);
      }
    }
    var colBValidationRange = foundValues;
    var colBValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colBValidationRange).build();
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colBValidationRule);

  }

  //  Populate column C, D & E data validations
  if(activeCell.getColumn()>0 && activeCell.getColumn()<4 && activeCell.getRow()>1){

    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
    activeCell.offset(0, 2).clearDataValidations();
    activeCell.offset(0, 3).clearDataValidations();

    var ptadata=ptaSh.getRange(3,1,ptaSh.getLastRow(),3).getValues();
    var ptdata=ptSh.getRange(3,4,ptSh.getLastRow(),1).getValues();

    for(var i=0;i<ptadata.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==ptadata[i][0]) {
        foundValues.push(ptdata[i][0]);
      }
      if(valueToFind==ptadata[i][1]) {
        foundValues2.push(ptdata[i][0]);
      }
      if(valueToFind==ptadata[i][2]) {
        foundValues3.push(ptdata[i][0]);
      }
    }
    var colCValidationRange = foundValues;
    var colCValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colCValidationRange).build();
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colCValidationRule);
    var colDValidationRange = foundValues2;
    var colDValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colDValidationRange).build();
    activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(colDValidationRule);
    var colEValidationRange = foundValues3;
    var colEValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colEValidationRange).build();
    activeCell.offset(0, 3).setDataValidation(colEValidationRule);
  }
}
```

Take a look at these references.  Understanding arrays is crucial to understanding how to loop through data.

[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
[getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())

Comment: Thanks @MiMi!  I was having difficulty with `indexof` and just changed that to `activecell` and completely forgot to revert back.  I'll play with your answer a bit.  I received an error it first on line 12 `var data=ptSh.getRange(3,1,ptSh.getLastRow(),2).getValues(); // changed ptaSht`  That populated column B, but it's not working for column C yet.  I'll keep messing with it and see if I can understand what's going on in there.  Thank you very much!

Comment: You probably now this but the command `indexof()` is spelled `indexOf()`

Comment: sorry.  i was being lazy.  I should know better on here by now.  I was having trouble with `&&` operator earlier and that seems to be where things are hanging up again... `if(activeCell.getColumn()>1 && activeCell.getColumn<4 && activeCell.getRow()>1)`

Comment: Script just stops at that point.  Nothing in error or execution log and I'm logging where the `activeCell` is and it's col 2 row 5.  should fit the criteria

Comment: I inserted the parenthesis into my answer.

Comment: I updated this line: `if(activeCell.getColumn()>0 && activeCell.getColumn()<4 && activeCell.getRow()>1)`

Comment: Does the execution log have any thing noteworthy in it?

Comment: Not that I can see.  But I missed those `()` earlier... I'm going through and adding `Logger` lines to see if I can pinpoint where it's acting up.  Col B populates fine, but C does not.  I also kept `activeCell.getColumn()>0` at `activeCell.getColumn()>1`.  The `offset` was throwing the responses off.  I did add a link to my sheet if you want to move the conversation there

Comment: If you could update your current script in the bottom of your question perhaps I could be more helpful.

Comment: I can work with what you've done though.  I don't want anyone to feel like I just expect them to do all of the work.  You've given me some good guidance to work with.  Thank you!

Comment: I like the idea of combining the functions, but I think the offsets are messing things up.  That's why I had each column data validation split up depending on the active cell.

Comment: If I could better understand what you're trying to do, I'm sure I can fix it.

Comment: Updated the OP.  Sorry.  I'm the worst at explaining what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Let me suggest that you treat each new question as though none of us now anything about the past questions.  Just provide a complete description every time.